# R shiny dashboard table menuitem with sub item

Tags: r, shiny

I have a table in a R shiny dashboard but when i add a menu sub item under that table, nothing renders to the screen anymore

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(
       sidebarMenu(
          menuItem("Table" , tabname = "my_table", icon = icon("table"),
              menuSubItem("sub menu",
                          tabName = "subMenu")),
          menuItem("Next Widget", tabName = "Other"))),

    dashboardBody(
          tabItems(
             tabItem(tabName = "my_table",
               fluidRow(DT::dataTableOutput("example_table")
               )),
             tabItem(tabName = "Other",
                     h2("Other tab")
)
)))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are on the right way - use the `menuSubItem`s ID in `dashboardBody()`.

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem("Table" , tabname = "my_table", icon = icon("table"),
                     startExpanded = TRUE,
                     menuSubItem("sub menu",
                                 tabName = "subMenu")),
            menuItem("Next Widget", tabName = "Other"))),
    
    dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            tabItem(tabName = "subMenu", #my_table",
                    h2("First tab")
            ),
            tabItem(tabName = "Other",
                    h2("Other tab")
            )
        )))
server <- function(input, output) {
    
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```